# ¿Esta bien esta condición en PHP?

Tags: php, formularios, condiciones, validación

Estoy haciendo una validación de un campo `tel` en un formulario que hice en HTML, la validación la estoy haciendo con PHP. Lo que intento hacer es que primero compruebe si los datos son numéricos para eso uso `!filter_var($tel, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)`, después si tiene el formato adecuado (solo numero con un ancho definido en diez) para eso uso una expresión regular `preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $tel)`  y finalmente imprimó un mensaje en pantalla si no se cumple la condición.

```
if(empty($_POST["tel"])){
        $error.="Ingrese un numero de teléfono </br>";
    }else{
        $tel=$_POST["tel"];
        if(!filter_var($tel, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)){
            $error.="El campo teléfono solo admite números </br>";
        }else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $tel)){
            $tel=!preg_match($tel, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        }else{
            $error.="El campo teléfono debe de contener diez números </br>";
        }
    }
```

Ese es el código, pero tengo duda en esta parte:

```
else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $tel)){
            $tel=!preg_match($tel, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        }else{
            $error.="El campo teléfono debe de contener diez números </br>";
        }
```

Ya que no sé si así esta bien estructurada. De igual manera si ustedes tienen otro método estoy dispuesto a aprender, pero me gustaria que me dijeran si esta bien o no, si le falta o si le debe de quitar algo. De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Hiciste algunas pruebas del código? Si funciona o qué error tienes?

Comment: Si, el código funciona bien. Solo que tengo dudas de si esta bien estructurado. Me pasa lo de si ya funciona no le muevas.